# read data from .json file (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I develop game using TypeScript. I have level.json file, which generated by level editor. How I can load this file in 
my game and read data from it?

Comment: What environment ? Node JS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplistically speaking, you could load it with an AJAX call and parse the JSON:

```
function levelRequestListener () {
    var levels = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(levels);
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = levelRequestListener;
request.open("get", "level.json", true);
request.send();
```

You could take this up a level by writing an interface to describe the levels structure so you could get type checking and auto-completion on the `levels` variable...

```
interface Level {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

function levelRequestListener () {
    var levels: Level[] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(levels[0].name);
}
```