# How Parse .JSON File in Ionic 2 Angular 2

Tags: json, parsing, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need help about Ionic 2, I can make this on Ionic 1, So in this update is impossible, I want to parse Data from a JSON file:

```
{
  "-KVNx9n6hIKfp0ELMDTH": {
    "complete": "Some content",
    "content": "Some subtitle",
    "date": "1 ENE",
    "id": "1",
    "image": "Imagen",
    "title": "Some title"
  }
}
```

To my Home.ts (typescript) script, I want show the image item on a `Ion-card`

I need help!

Thanks very much. :)

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301829/read-data-from-json-file-typescript can help you.

Comment: yes, this was a good help, so i not tell about the JSON file is in Firebase Realtime Database, So i need that the app read JSON data from a server.   Anyway, thanks :)